# What is the length of time for each fusion process in a massive star?

Tags: star, nucleosynthesis

In a massive star (i.e. an O5 star), first hydrogen is fused into helium, then helium is fused into carbon. This process continues to neon, oxygen, and finally silicon burning. So I am wondering, how long does it take for each process to commence?

Comment: Here's a timetable for a 25 $M_\odot$ star. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_II_supernova#Formation

Comment: @PM2Ring You can use this in an answer :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My stellar astrophysics text, Francis LeBlanc's *An Introduction to Stellar Astrophysics*, gives the following quantities for the stages of burning in a $25M_{\odot}$ star (citing models by [Arnould & Samyn 2001](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001AnPh...26e...1A/abstract)). This is somewhat less massive than a typical main sequence O5-type star, and with higher masses come higher core temperatures and shorter evolutionary timescales. Nonetheless, it should give you a reasonable order-of-magnitude idea of how long it takes for these processes to play out in a massive star.

| Phase | Central temperature (K) | Timescale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hydrogen | $6.0\times10^7$ | $7\times10^6$ years |
| Helium | $2.0\times10^8$ | $5\times10^5$ years |
| Carbon | $9.0\times10^8$ | $600$ years |
| Neon | $1.7\times10^9$ | $0.5$ years |
| Oxygen | $2.4\times10^9$ | 6 days |
| Silicon | $4.0\times10^9$ | 1 days |

(One major caveat is that these models are two decades old, and stellar evolutionary codes are constantly being improved. However, I don't believe that these are old enough to be significantly out-of-date!)